# Switching shells for one cron job

Tags: shell, zsh, cron

Say I have the following in my `crontab`:

```
* * * * * command1 -option A; command2; command3; etc.
```

I would like `cron` to run the commands I have in that line with a specific shell. How can I do that?

I know that I could technically put these commands in a file, add the corresponding shebang, and then just ask `cron` to run that shell script, but I would like to avoid that. Is there any way I can have `cron` run a set of commands in a specific shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your cron string to:

```
 * * * * *     /bin/sh commannd1..; /bin/tcsh command2... ; /bin/zsh command3
```

This is the more extreme case.  But you can prefix the name of the specific shell before the commands.

Another option is echo all the commands to the specific shell

```
 * * * * *    echo 'comand1...;command2....;command3...' | /bin/sh
```

Comment: I think you need to add the `-c` option to each command on the first line.

Comment: hmmm....possible if the unnamed shell has a -c option.